# javascript window condition is not working

Tags: javascript, html, window, size, conditional-statements

I am trying to make the condition work. I cannot use media queries since my function requires the press of a button to work.

Edit:
My website is supposed to change the top navbar into a sidebar that opens and closes when the window size decreases to a certain point.

I added a lot more details, this is all of my code (includes html, css and javascript):

```css
body {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 margin: 0%;
 font-family: Arial;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 background: linear-gradient(#e6e6e6, white);
 height: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background: #80bfff;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 border-radius: 25px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #f2f2f2;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 background: #3399ff;
}

.header {
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 font-size: 187%;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 1.5%;
 background-color: white;
 color: grey;
 z-index: 2;
}

.content {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.card p {
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.card p:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.card a {
 float: left;
 color: grey;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 0.7%;
 padding-bottom: 0.7%;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.card a:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
 color: #3399ff;
}

.navigation {
 z-index: 1;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: visible;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: auto;
}

#sidebar {
 width: 100%;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1%;
 font-size: 100%;
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover:not(.active), .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 3;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
 .navigation {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
 }

 li a, .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 
 .dropdown-content {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 50%;
 }

 .closebtn {
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 16px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
 }
 
 .about a {
  left: 20.4px;
  float: left;
 }
 
 .closebtn:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 
 #main1 {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
 }
 
 #main2 {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
 }
 
 .header {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }
 
 .header span {
  color: #3399ff;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 
 #sidebar {
  width: 0px;
 }
 
 .card {
  margin-top: 10%;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
 .closebtn {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .header span {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .navigation {
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 #sidebar {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 min-width: 1%;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 color: grey;
 padding: 10%;
 width: 80%;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: white;
}

.active {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}

.about a {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
}

.active:hover {
 background-color: #80bfff;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 transition: 0.5s;
}

br.clearLeft {
   clear: left;        
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

<title>Testing</title>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$(window).resize(function() {
 var w = $(window).width();
 
 if (w < 1000) {
  function(openNav() {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
   document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "250px";
   document.getElementById("main2").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  });
  function(closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0px";
   document.getElementById("main1").style.marginLeft = "0px";
   document.getElementById("main2").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  });
 }

 if (w > 1000) {
  function(openNav() {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "100%";
  });
  function(closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "100%";
  });
 }
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id = "main1"; class = "header";>
 <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
 Website
</div>

<div id = "sidebar"; class = "navigation";>
 <li><a class = "active" href = "#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class = "dropdown">
   <a class = "dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
   <div class = "dropdown-content">
    <a href = "#link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href = "#link2">Link 2</a>
    <a href = "#link3">Link 3</a>
   </div>
  </li>
 <li class = "about";><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
 <br class="clearLeft" />
</div>

<div id = "main2"; class = "content";>
<div class = "card";>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: some debug? console.log(w)?

Comment: 'functionName' not defined:                                              (function(event){"functionName"()
})

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you should be mainly using the power of media queries for this.

```js
function openNav(){
    $('body').addClass('open');
}

function closeNav(){
    $('body').removeClass('open');
}
```

```css
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0%;
    font-family: Arial;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background: linear-gradient(#e6e6e6, white);
    height: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #80bfff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background: #3399ff;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 187%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1.5%;
    background-color: white;
    color: grey;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.card p {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.card p:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.card a {
    float: left;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-top: 0.7%;
    padding-bottom: 0.7%;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.card a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    color: #3399ff;
}

.navigation {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 100%;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1%;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover:not(.active), .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 3;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .navigation {
        z-index: 2;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .closebtn {
        width: auto;
        float: right;
        padding: 6px 16px 6px 16px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .about a {
        left: 20.4px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .closebtn:hover {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    #main1 {
        transition: margin-left 0.5s;
    }
    
    #main2 {
        transition: margin-left 0.5s;
    }
    
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .header span {
        color: #3399ff;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    #sidebar {
        width: 0px;
    }
    
    .card {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .open #sidebar{
        width:250px;
    }

    .open #main1 {
        margin-left:250px;
    }

    .open #main2 {
        margin-left:250px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .closebtn {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .header span {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .navigation {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #sidebar {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    min-width: 1%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: grey;
    padding: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
}

.about a {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.active:hover {
    background-color: #80bfff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

br.clearLeft {
   clear: left;        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id = "main1"; class = "header";>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    Website
</div>

<div id = "sidebar"; class = "navigation";>
    <li><a class = "active" href = "#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class = "dropdown">
            <a class = "dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
            <div class = "dropdown-content">
                <a href = "#link1">Link 1</a>
                <a href = "#link2">Link 2</a>
                <a href = "#link3">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    <li class = "about";><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
    <br class="clearLeft" />
</div>

<div id = "main2"; class = "content";>
<div class = "card";>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
        Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
        Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
        Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
        Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
        Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
        Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
        Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
        Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
        Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
        Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
        Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
        Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
        Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
        Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
        Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
        Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
        Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
        Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
        Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
        Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I had to edit my actual code to make it simpler/more 'generalised' (there were 2 functions for each condition in my actual code). Your fix didn't work for my actual code.

Comment: There must be a problem in the other part of the code then. Can you update your question to include the whole source?

Comment: Ok, I just edited the question to include all my code